# codeiginiter setting a session error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I am trying to set a session in codeigniter from controller when all the credentials of the user is validated. I have this code in my login controller's method. Method '`login_check`' is called by the form_validation's set rules method as a callback function. I tried every possible way but for some reason I can't set the session which should be a straight forward task according to CI's manual

**Note: session is autoloaded in autoload.php**

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|callback_login_check');


public function login_check($password) {
    $this->load->library('session');
    //Field validation succeeded.&nbsp; Validate against database
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $this->load->model('industry_person');

    //query the database
    $query = $this->industry_person->check_login($username, $password);

    if (!$query) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('login_check', 'Invalid username or password');
        return false;
        $this->index();
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        if (!$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $data))
            echo "error setting session";

    }
}
```

I receive the output as '**error setting session**' when I put correct credentials and if they match in database.

Comment: You've set an encryption key, right?

Comment: `if (!$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', '$data'))`  $data has quotes round it - and shouldn't - it's a variable holding your array.  Also set_userdata takes ONLY the array, not the tring 'logged_in' you're passing.

Comment: Yes i have set the encryption key

Answer (score 2):

remove single quote from `$data`. It is an array variable. Try this,

```
if (!$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $data))
            echo "error setting session";
```

Comment: Yup, you're passing data as a string, not an array.

Comment: Oh sorry it was already removed but when I edited it on stackoverflow, I forgot to remove single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Because `$data` is an array .. give a try

```
if (!$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $data))
            echo "error setting session";
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work when I changed the encryption key in config.php file. The encryption key before involved '_' and new one just has only alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 0):

using session in codeigniter is based on the array, To initialize the Session class manually in your controller constructor, use the $this->load->library function:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

A useful aspect of the session array is that you can add your own data to it and it will be stored in the user's cookie. Why would you want to do this? Here's one example:

Let's say a particular user logs into your site. Once authenticated, you could add their username and email address to the session cookie, making that data globally available to you without having to run a database query when you need it.

To add your data to the session array involves passing an array containing your new data to this function

```
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

Where $array is an associative array containing your new data. Here's an example:

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Any piece of information from the session array is available using the following function:

```
$this->session->userdata('item');
```

eg:

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
    //do what you wanna do
}
```